# In IDA what does db and dd offset means in data section?

Tags: ida

So, in `.data` section there is some variable, and after it there is `db` or `dd` (`offset`). What exactly does this mean? And what does “align” means? Is there any Wiki or something like that that tells all this in detail?

```
    .data:0048A374                 db    0
    .data:0048A375                 db    0
    .data:0048A376                 db    0
    .data:0048A377                 db    0
    .data:0048A378 off_48A378      dd offset unk_48A000    ; DATA XREF: start+41↑o
    .data:0048A37C                 dd offset unk_48A1CE
    .data:0048A380                 dd offset unk_48A1CE
    .data:0048A384                 dd offset unk_48A33C
    .data:0048A388 byte_48A388     db 1                    ; DATA XREF: __InitVCL+3↑r
    .data:0048A389                 align 10h
    .data:0048A390                 dd offset WinMain
    .data:0048A394                 dd offset __matherr
    .data:0048A398                 dd offset __matherrl
    .data:0048A39C                 align 10h
    .data:0048A3A0                 dd offset unk_48F66C
    .data:0048A3A4                 dd offset off_490784
    .data:0048A3A8                 dd offset off_490788
    .data:0048A3AC                 dd offset __handle_setargv
    .data:0048A3B0                 dd offset __handle_exitargv
    .data:0048A3B4                 dd offset __handle_wsetargv
    .data:0048A3B8                 dd offset __handle_wexitargv
    .data:0048A3BC                 dd offset dword_48F0EC
    .data:0048A3C0 byte_48A3C0     db 0                    ; DATA XREF: ___CRTL_VCL_Init_2+2↑r
    .data:0048A3C0                                         ; __InitVCL+17↑r
    .data:0048A3C1 byte_48A3C1     db 0                    ; DATA XREF: .text:00401060↑r
    .data:0048A3C1                                         ; ___CRTL_VCL_Init_2+B↑r ...
    .data:0048A3C2                 dd offset unk_4906E4
    .data:0048A3C6                 dd offset unk_4907AC
    .data:0048A3CA                 dd offset unk_4904F0
    .data:0048A3CE                 db    0
    .data:0048A3CF ; DWORD dwTlsIndex
    .data:0048A3CF dwTlsIndex      dd 0                    ; DATA XREF: start:loc_401012↑r
    .data:0048A3CF                                         ; .text:00401082↑r ...
    .data:0048A3D3 dword_48A3D3    dd 0                    ; DATA XREF: start+1A↑w
    .data:0048A3D7 dword_48A3D7    dd 0                    ; DATA XREF: start+4D↑w
    .data:0048A3D7                                         ; .text:__getHInstance↑r ...
    .data:0048A3DB                 db  90h ; ђ
    .data:0048A3DC ; Exported entry 156. ___CPPdebugHook
    .data:0048A3DC                 public ___CPPdebugHook
    .data:0048A3DC ___CPPdebugHook db    0                 ; DATA XREF: start+E↑o
    .data:0048A3DC                                         ; sub_46AF30+20↑o ...
    .data:0048A3DD                 db    0
    .data:0048A3DE                 db    0
    .data:0048A3DF                 db    0
```

Comment: define: b - byte, d - dword

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. While your question is certainly valid, it's also trivial and the answer can be found in the first pages of books about x86 assembly language. E.g. [here](https://www.randallhyde.com/AssemblyLanguage/) or [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly) ... aside from that it's be best to paste text as text and not a screenshot. Because: search engines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `db` means “**d**efine **b**yte”, i.e. a reservation of **1** byte of memory,
- `dw` means “**d**efine **w**ord” (**2** bytes of memory),
- `dd` means “**d**efine **d**ouble-word” (**4** bytes of memory).

The `offset` prefix means to fill the reserved byte(s) *not with the mentioned data itself (i.e., *not with the content*),* but only with the *offset* to it (i.e., with the **position** of data in memory, expressed as the number of bytes from the beginning of the segment).

The `align` directive means “If this address is not a multiple of the given number, skip the necessary number of bytes to fulfill this address requirement for the next data”.

---

You may see it in your listing:

- `db 1`  is at address `0048a388`, it occupies only **1** byte (`db` – **d**efine **b**yte, i.e., **1** byte) and fills  it with the given value (`1`). So the next address is `0048a389`.
- At this next address (`0048a389`) is the `align 10h` directive, so the byte at this address and the subsequent 6 bytes at addresses

  - `0048a38a`, `0048a388b`, `0048a38c`, `0048a38d`, `0048a38e`, and `0048a38f`

  are *skipped,* because they *don't fulfill* the request “a multiple of 10h” (i.e., their last digit in hexadecimal notation is *not* `0`).
- At the next address `0048a390` (which finally fulfills the `align 10h` requirement) is the directive

  - `dd offset WinMain`,

  which reserves 4 bytes of memory (`dd` – **d**efine **d**ouble word), and fills them with the *offset* of the (start of) `WinMain` function (`offset WinMain`).